# jQuery load with GET request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have created a forum in my spare time and I wanted to add Ajax to it to pick up old knowledge. For a start I just wanted to add it to the thread page which displays the main thread post with the thread reply's (like a normal thread page of a forum) so when a user submitted a reply with the text area underneath the thread reply's, it would just reload the threads with the new reply.

My threads page has the url with the thread id to load from the database (threads_posts.php?threadID=1). How do I send the data (threadID=1) of the current URL to another page using the load function?

thread_posts.php

```
<div id="content"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content").load("thread_posts_load.php");
})
</script>
```

thread_posts_load.php

```
<?php
$threadID = $_GET['threadID'];
?>
```

Comment: Check javascript `document.location` object, there you find current URI

Comment: I found that while I was looking for a solution and was mainly wondering if there was easier way to just pass the data straight through another page. I appreciate the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery ajax function like this

```
   $.ajax({
        url: 'thread_posts_load.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {threadID:'YOUR_ID'},
        success: function (data) {
             $("#content").html(data);
        }
    });
```

Or load function like this

```
  var ID = "YOUR_ID";

  $("#content").load("thread_posts_load.php?threadID=" + ID);
```